# Mean.js Query var not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Im using Mean.js to create a blog, i installed it with npm, and i create crud module comment to comment each article, and i save some comment with `article` id as reference. and i create api route in server.

```
  // Comments Routes
 app.route('/api/comments/:articleId').all()
    .get(comments.listbyArticle);
```

on server cotroller

```
    exports.listbyArticle = function(req, res) {

    Comment.find( {article : req.articleId }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, comments) {
       if (err) {
         return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
         });
       } else {
         res.jsonp(comments);
       }
     });
   };
```

but when navigate to this route

```
http://localhost:3000/api/comments/57550c21612bc90478333017
```

it response all comments except this article id, if i hard code (`'57550c21612bc90478333017'`) the article id instead of `req.articleId`.Then response shows me proper comments.

please explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Value is coming properly for `req.articleId`?

Comment: no, its not coming properly, i think req.articleId is empty or null, how can i check whats inside `req` ? i try to return req with response but when i do route breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)** to access the articleId in the URL:

```
exports.listbyArticle = function(req, res) {
    var articleId = req.params.articleId;
    Comment.find( {article: articleId }).sort('-created')
           .populate('user', 'displayName')
           .exec(function(err, comments) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    res.jsonp(comments);
                }
            });
};
```